# Trouble referencing an outlet

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

I seem to be having trouble referencing my outlet, I finally got the drag and drop working, (with some help from a stackoverflow member) but still cant get this outlet to work.

```
class controller(NSWindow):


    form_file = IBOutlet()
    mainWindow = IBOutlet()


    #drag and drop ability
    def awakeFromNib(self):
        self.registerForDraggedTypes_([NSFilenamesPboardType, None])
        print 'registerd drag type'


    def draggingEntered_(self, sender):
        print 'dragging entered'
        pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        types = pboard.types()
        opType = NSDragOperationNone
        if NSFilenamesPboardType in types:
            opType = NSDragOperationCopy
        return opType


    def performDragOperation_(self, sender):
        print 'preform drag operation'
        pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        successful = False
        if NSFilenamesPboardType in pboard.types():
            fileAStr = pboard.propertyListForType_(NSFilenamesPboardType)[0].encode('utf-8')
            successful = True

        #edit some things
        print type(fileAStr)
        self.form_file.setStringValue_(fileAStr)
        return successful
```

I can drop the file but I am unable to refrence the `form_file` outlet from inside of the `performDragOperation` function.  I want to update the NSTextField with the URL from the dropped file but it returns a `NoneType` error.

```
(reason '<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable') was raised     during a dragging session
```

I was trying to catch errors so I added the following in my `awakeFromNib` function

```
    print type(self.formfile)
    print type(self.mainWindow)
    NSLog("formfile = %p", self.formfile)
    NSLog("mainWindow = %p", self.mainWindow)
    NSLog("self = %p", self)
    print self
```

Which would return this:

```
registerd drag type
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
2013-01-12 16:32:29.211 app [463:303] formfile = 0x10013c148
2013-01-12 16:32:29.212 app[463:303] mainWindow = 0x10013c148
2013-01-12 16:32:29.212 app[463:303] self = 0x105aba890
<controller: 0x1008a1600>
registerd drag type
<objective-c class NSTextField at 0x7fff785296e8>
<objective-c class controller at 0x10541b6a0>
2013-01-12 16:32:29.216 app[463:303] formfile = 0x105abaa10
2013-01-12 16:32:29.216 app[463:303] mainWindow = 0x105abaa10
2013-01-12 16:32:29.216 app[463:303] self = 0x105aba890
<controller: 0x1008afe00>
```

But If I do the same test in the draggingEntered function then I only get one controller and objects (the `NoneType` one).  The problem is it's running awakeFromNib method twice right?  I thought it may be a issue with my xib file but I've gone over it and cant seem to figure out the issue.

any ideas,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

As I am unfamiliar with Python, my suggestion may or may not work…

If Python has classes and your file is a subclass, try calling the superclass in `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Calling a superclass from within a function wouldn't fix the fact that the function (awakeFromNib) is being called twice and yielding different results.